# How to put a session variable value into string

Tags: php, string

How to put session value into this string in PHP

```
$query = '//Users/User/username[. =  "admin"]';
```

So instead of admin I need to put `$_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];`

Comment: Instead of XPath result or what?

Comment: Wasn't this page useful? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you mate

```
$query = '//Users/User/'.$_SESSION["SESS_FIRST_NAME"];
```

Assuming the data in the Session is "Joe" this will output:

```
//Users/User/Joe
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$query = '//Users/User/'.$_SESSION["SESS_FIRST_NAME"];`

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] is just like normal variable so either directly replace it with admin or store its value in a variable

```
$admin = $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
$query = '//Users/User/username[. =  ". $admin . "]';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = '//Users/User/username[. =  "'.$_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'].'"]';
```